# Let $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R^3$ be defined by $f(x)=\langle 8x,6x,−8x\rangle$. Is f a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am not sure on what process I should have when dealing with this problem?

I don't know what f(y) is equal to..

To fill in the blanks, the answers must be be written as a formula that returns a vector, which can be done using angle brackets.

For example:<8,6,-8> which is a result with 3 dimensions.
If I put a result that doesn't have 3 dimensions, then I will get an error.

In the "choose" drop-down menu for part a) and part b), it has 2 options that can be selected. The 2 options are "Yes, they are equal" and "No, they are not equal"

For part c), the two options are "f is a linear transformation" and "f is not a linear transformation"

Comment: Check the conditions for linearity and you’re done!

Comment: For finding whether its a LT, you will have to check 2 properties: a) Additivity and b) Homogenity. Additivity says that $f(x+y)$ = $f(x)$ + $f(y)$, and homogenity says that $f(c.x)$ = $c.f(x)$, for all c,x $\in$ Reals. My solution basically shows that.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[image]

Please find the solution, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I'm still not sure why f(y) = <8y,6y,-8y> ? Does that come from f(x) = <8x,6x,-8x> ?

Comment: It doesn’t come entirely from f(x), it’s just another vector which has a similar structure and pattern that u get in f(x).

Comment: So if I had something like f(x) = <x, 2x^2, 5x> would that mean f(y) = <y, 2y^2, 5y> ?
Does f(y) always have the same values as f(x), but using the y variable?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It’s like a function of variable y, just like f(x) which is a function of a variable x. So, it will contain the exact same values of x, just replace y with x and keep everything same. That’s it!!

Answer (score 1):

When we write $f(x) = \langle 8x,6x,-8x \rangle$, it means that $f$ *assigns* to each real number $x$ the 3-dimensional vector $\langle 8x,6x,-8x \rangle$. Thus, for example, $f(1) = \langle 8,-6,-8 \rangle$ and $f(0)$ is the zero vector.

So, $f(y)$ is just the vector $\langle 8y,6y,-8y \rangle$ and $f(x+y)$ is...

It is easy to check that, in fact, $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: I'm still not sure why f(y) = <8y,6y,-8y> ? Does that come from f(x) = <8x,6x,-8x> ? 
Why does f(y) have the same values as f(x),but just different variables?